# Software update for HWE_EOL failed; Updater never recovered

Tags: updates, security, hardware-enablement-stack

Couple weeks ago there's this prompt to update the Hardware Enablement Stack. The exact message says,

"New important security and hardware support update.
Warning : security update for your current Hardware Enablement Stack
ended on 2016-08-04"

I clicked "Install" and that led to

"Package dependencies cannot be resolved"

Is there anything I should do ? 
[image]
Ubuntu 14.04

## EDIT

I ran this line,

```
 sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-core-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-xenial libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xenial
```

and got the following errors, captured in 5 screen shots
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This page https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack shows the terminal commands needed to perform the HWE update for 14.04. I suggest you do that, then come back here, and edit your question to include the error messages you received.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Any thought? Ubuntu crashed mysteriously last night. That makes me a bit worried that something's been removed from running that command.

Comment: The error is related to a dkms (i.e. kernel module) update associated with a package named oem-audio-hda-daily or something.  Is this something you added via a ppa? I am not familiar with this package. I suggest you start by finding out what this is, and then see if you can remove it.

Comment: I searched for this package in synaptic and didn't find it, which means it is probably coming from a ppa.

Comment: Perhaps it's from here? https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/ubuntu/alsa-daily  and maybe you did this: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS

Comment: That last page contains uninstall instructions.

Comment: I suggest you uninstall that package, retry the command line HWE update, and if all goes well and you need that package, reinstall it.